# Linkedin rest Api - Getting Email address

Tags: linkedin-api

we are developing an Application to do single signon with LinkedIn. In our app we have requested r_basicProfile and r_emailaddress permissions in scope. But once the user is authenticated while retreiving the email address, we are able to get the primary email address alone.

is there a way we could get all the email address the user has added to his profile?